# Access all elements after stream filter

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

My task is to filter an array, change the remaining elements and return the array with both the changed and unchanged values. My code:

```
return Arrays.stream(sentence.split(" "))
    .filter(/* do some filter to each value */)
    .map(/* map this value*/)
    .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

How can I return an array of the changed **and** unchanged values?

Comment: it's unclear what you're asking. so you expect to return an array but instead, your terminal operation is returning a `String`. could you provide some sample data and the expected result?

Comment: Sorry, i'm take string, split her, do some with words that are longer than some number and returned changed and unchanged word in some String.
For example:
take Hey fellow warriors, return Hey wollef sroirraw(reverse word that longer than 5)

Comment: Give some example and show how do you use this method?

Comment: @Raviprakash the OP has already mentioned that they want to modify only certain elements after splitting and then return both changed and unchanged elements combined into one string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`filter` removes elements. If you don't want to remove elements, but rather just change some of them, you can use [`?:`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) or if-else inside `map` to selectively change elements.

For example:

```
System.out.println(Stream.of("abc", "def", "ghi")
    .map(a -> a.equals("def") ? "xyz" : a)
    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Or:

```
System.out.println(Stream.of("abc", "def", "ghi")
    .map(a -> {
       if (a.equals("def"))
          return "xyz";
       else
          return a;
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

This will only change the element which equals `def` to `xyz` (for each other element, it will simply keep that element as is) and the output will be:

```
[abc, xyz, ghi]
```

Comment: Your answer seems like what the OP wants Although, `Arrays.asList("abc", "def", "ghi").stream()` can be improved with `Stream.of("abc", "def", "ghi")`.

Answer (score 3):

We can achieve this without stream also.

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("abc", "def", "ghi");
list.replaceAll(s -> s.equals("def") ? "xyz" : s);
System.out.println(list);
```

**Output**

```
[abc, xyz, ghi]
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest option would be to use the `map` intermediate operation along with the ternary operator as mentioned by Dukeling, but another variant would be:

```
 String result = 
          Pattern.compile(" ")
                 .splitAsStream(sentence)
                 .map(s -> criteria ? modification : s) // partly pseudocode
                 .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```